# How to GET from a backend using Axios on an Expo app

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I'm trying to do a `Get` request from my Flask backend to work on the web browser emulation of my expo react-native app. Unfortunately, the web browser emulator doesn't seem to use the same internal IP addresses as the rest of my system.

Here's my proxy from `package.json`: `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:50001"`

Then my axios request on the expo react-native app:

```
axios.get('/').then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("error");
      });
```

Postmaning the request from the backend works great, I get the expected .json result. However, the expo react axios request receives the entire `index.html` file from the expo app itself.

Answer (score 0):

if your server and mobile device are under same network, use the local ip of server/system instead of 127.0.0.1.

To find local ip, run ipconfig ( for windows) or ifconfig (for linux/mac) in terminal

Comment: I went to whatismyip.com and got 128.125.148.79, so I set the proxy in `package.json` to `proxy": "http://128.125.148.79:50001`.

Unfortunately, it's still not working, still getting the `index.html` page

Comment: @BigSteve, that is your public ip, use local ip instead
run ipconfig ( for windows) or ifconfig (for linux/mac) to find it

Comment: Yeah that's still not working, I'm still getting the index.html. I changed the proxy in package.json to the new IP, do I need to change it elsewhere?

Comment: I changed the axios address to my local ip, got this error: `ccess to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:50001/' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Answer (score 0):

You have to find out the IP Address of your pc and then you can fetch (or axios) against it.

Hint: You have to take your real IP Address and not the whatsmyip sh*t!

Example: I have an api/login route and my ip is 192.164.50.44 + port is 8080 then I can do something like this:

```
fetch("http://192.164.50.44:8080/api/login")
```

ofc you can use axios instead of fetch.